# Como implemento SharedReferences en Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-intent, sharedpreferences

Buen dia,
Tengo un modelo de codigo usando intent de la siguiente manera y quiero pasarlo, nose como se usa SharedReferences

```
        unidades=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextunidades);
        Intent miinten = new Intent(Calculate.this, Hitorial.class);
        u= unidades.getText().toString();

        miinten.putExtra("u", u);
        startActivity(miinten);
```

Y en la activity 2 en mi caso Hitorial tengo

```
private String uni;

 Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    if(bundle !=null) {
        uni =bundle.getString("u");
    }
```

lo que deseo es poder usar references para ese valor que se guarde en uni, quiero guardarlo una vez y tenerlo en la app ya guardado siempre y poder operarlo y tenerlo como acumulado

Comment: Explica que es lo que deseas, en activity 2 recibes el valor y deseas guardarlo en preferencias? cuando deseas obtener el valor de preferencias?

Comment: Jorge gracias,Edite la pregunta, pero es basicamente que quiero guardar ese dato Uni una sola vez en la app y tenerlo para operarlo en la activity2 y acumularlo

Comment: Si me puedes ayudar te lo agradeceria

Comment: ok lo recibes en la Activity 2 y lo guardas, pero si lo vuelves a enviar ya no usara el valor enviado si no el guardado? @Julian

Comment: Asi es el valor guardado es el que debe usarse como un acumulado

Answer (score 0):

Agrega los metodos para guardar y obtener el valor de preferencias:

```
private String PREFS_KEY = "mispreferencias";

public void guardaValor(Context context, String text) {
    SharedPreferences settings = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_KEY, MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    editor = settings.edit();
    editor.putString("valorU", text);
    editor.commit();
}



public String obtieneValor(Context context) {
    SharedPreferences preferences = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_KEY, MODE_PRIVATE);
    return  preferences.getString("valorU", "");
}
```

Posteriormente en Activity 2 debes validar si este valor ha sido guardado, si es asi se obtiene de preferencias de otra forma se obtiene del bundle y se guarda en preferencias:

```
String valorU = obtieneValor(getApplicationContext());
if(valorU == null || valorU.length() == 0){
//No existe valor guardado en preferencias.
//Obtiene valor de intent y guarda en preferencias.
  Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
      if(bundle !=null) {
          uni =bundle.getString("u");
          guardaValor(getApplicationContext(), uni);
      }
}else{
//asigna valor que fue guardado previamente en preferencias.
 uni = valorU;
}
```

Comment: Gracias Amigo, ya lo pongo a prueba y le cuento

Comment: No me funcion se detiene la app :(

Comment: Debes revisar el LogCat, la app se puede detener por infinidad de causas.